# How i can use REGEXP+mysql+procedure together

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating function to find category by id. Because of categories values are stored in mysql database with php serialize and encoded json result looks like this :

```
"a:2:{i:0;s:1:\"1\";i:1;s:2:\"50\";}"
```

I can use simple mysql statement and that's working fine with REGEXP :

```
SELECT * FROM provider_cat_subcat WHERE category_id REGEXP '\\"\50.\\"'
```

But i want to create procedure so i can put variable value. So when i am trying this :

```
WHERE provider_cat_subcat.category_id REGEXP '\\"' + cat_id + '.\"'
```

it's not working i think because REGEXP. Please help me to know how i can join variable with REGEXP or there's why i can use php.

Full procedure:

```
BEGIN 
   SELECT * FROM provider_cat_subcat 
   WHERE provider_cat_subcat.category_id REGEXP '\\"' + cat_id + '.\"'
   AND provider_cat_subcat.subcategory_id REGEXP '\\"' + subcat_id + '.\"'; 
END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try that please ?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE cat_regexp_search(IN cat_id int(11), IN sub_cat_id int(11))
BEGIN
  SET @cat_id    := cat_id;
  SET @sub_cat_id := sub_cat_id;
   SELECT * FROM provider_cat_subcat 
   WHERE provider_cat_subcat.category_id REGEXP CONCAT('\\"', @cat_id, '.\\"')
   AND provider_cat_subcat.subcategory_id REGEXP CONCAT('\\"', @sub_cat_id, '.\\"'); 
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You should call this script as `CALL cat_regexp_search(1, 3);`
When do you want to edit then call as

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cat_regexp_search;
```

then execute create script again.

Comment: can't use simple variable rather then global ?

Comment: @BabbuMann I'm not quite fluent in SQL, but isn't that a local variable declaration?

Comment: @BabbuMann it may actually I'm not expert on mysql I was using as it, i didn't care it, but he/she may try and fix that as if need.

Comment: ooops @BabbuMann you are the author of question sorry I was mention about you as a third person :)

Comment: :) that is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM provider_cat_subcat 
   WHERE provider_cat_subcat.category_id REGEXP '^1[() -]*[[:digit:]]{3}[() -]*[[:digit:]]{3}[() -]*[[:digit:]]{4}$';
AND provider_cat_subcat.subcategory_id REGEXP '^1[() -]*[[:digit:]]{3}[() -]*[[:digit:]]{3}[() -]*[[:digit:]]{4}$';
END
```

try without slash

Comment: showing error :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND provider_cat_subcat.subcategory_id REGEXP '^1[() -]*[[:digit:]]{3}[() -]*[[:' at line 10